# Loop through checkbox form Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, foreach

I think I'm missing something small here. I'm new to Laravel and php. I'm getting an error when I try to submit this form with a foreach loop. Each interest should loop in a new insert into my table. Can you help guide me through this stackoverflow, I've read some other solutions but dont quite understand how to apply them to my problem? Here is everything I have:

**ERROR:**

```
ErrorException in InterestController.php line 45:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

$interests = $inputs->interests;------->line 45

**InterestController:**

```
public function store(){

    //Get all the post values
    $inputs = Request::all();
    //From the post values get the array of interest ids that you are sending
    $interests = $inputs->interests;
    //For each interest id, save a new entry in the my_interest table
    foreach ($interests as $interest) {
        $interested_in = new MyInterests;
        $interested_in->user_id = Auth::id();
        $interested_in->interest_id = $interest;
        $interested_in->save();
            //dd($interests);
        }

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
{!! Form::open(array('id'=> 'form1')) !!}

                             @foreach($interests as $interest)

                                    <div class = "form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                              <label><input type="checkbox" name = "interests[]" value="{{$interest->id}}">{{$interest->name}}</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            @endforeach

                                {!! Form:: submit('Sumbit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an array not an collect. your code should be.

```
$interests = $inputs['interests'];
```

Comment: ErrorException in InterestController.php line 47:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...when i add your code it says this.. any ideas?

Comment: may be you need to check if isset($inputs['interests']); because if you didn't check any the value is null. and that will cause error

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in 45 line,which line that? i supposed for another problem to get id you need to try like that

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: you can't access this $inputs->interests.In your query you did all() method.If you use find method or first method then you can access this field.

Answer (score 0):

First check if interests is Set

```
if(isset($interests)){
    foreach ($interests as $interest) {
        $interested_in = new MyInterests;
        $interested_in->user_id = Auth::id();
        $interested_in->interest_id = $interest;
        $interested_in->save();
        //dd($interests);
    }
}
```